# Digital Certificate for digitally signing a xml document

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I have 3rd party integration requirement that xml docs be digitally signed with the following parameters:
Signature keys shall be 256bit Elliptic Curve Keys, have a length of 256 bits, use the NIST SuiteB P-256 curve.
Do I need to to have a digital certificate to digitally sign a xml document, to meet the these (above) requirements.
or do the libraries for java or c# provide the capability to digitally sign while meeting these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a digital certificate. That does not mean you need to buy one. You could generate one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Thomas....If I generate a certificate myself, how would the signature keys, which I presume refers to public/private keys meet these requirements: "Signature keys shall be 256bit Elliptic Curve Keys, have a length of 256 bits, use the NIST SuiteB P-256 curve". How do I get

Comment: @user1080453: as described by others: https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/12/28/creating-self-signed-ecdsa-ssl-certificate-using-openssl/